# Android relative layout with button width using weight

Tags: android, layout, button, width

I've used the `layout_weight` parameter to set the width of the buttons at 70% of the total layout width, but it seems I'm missing some important detail in order to make it work.

(Another solution would be to work with `display.getWidth()` programmatically, but it doesn't work either, because I don't know what my .xml should look like If I choose to set the width with `button.setWidth()`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15px"  
        android:id="@+id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:id="@+id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_200"
        android:layout_above="@id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:id="@+id/dummyTextView"/>       
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:text="Σύνδεση"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyTextView"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/demoLoginButton"
        android:text="Δοκιμαστική χρήση"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout

Comment: on a side note it is not recommended to use px with textsize instead use sp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try This..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15px"  
        android:id="@+id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:id="@+id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_200"
        android:layout_above="@id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:id="@+id/dummyTextView"/>      
    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyTextView"
        android:id="@+id/loginButtonLayout"
        android:weightSum="1.0">  
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:text="Σύνδεση"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity = "center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginButtonLayout"
        android:weightSum="1.0">  
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/demoLoginButton"
            android:text="Δοκιμαστική χρήση"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works almost perfectly, the first button is a bit smaller than the second. I suspect it's the size of the text that matters.

Comment: For getting both the button of exact same size i.e. 70% of the screen's width, just change the width parameter of button to 
  android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: While this answer is valid, code does not explain itself. See below for a better overall answer, including code and thorough explanations of why it works.

Answer (score 28):

**The Problem**

You can't use the layout_weight parameters on a RelativeLayout. These are parameters from the LinearLayout. I'll give some more information about the differences later below. But first about the solution for this question

**A Solution**

Use a LinearLayout where you can position elements in a row with a weight distribution. **Don't forget to use the 0dp width when adding layout_weights though!** The below example shows a weight distribution of 70/30.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:text="left" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".70" /> 

    <Button
        android:text="right" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".30" />

</LinearLayout>
```

All this within the RelativeLayout you already had in your code. The rest of this answer is background information that everyone with these questions should read in order to understand what they're doing.

**RelativeLayout**

Whenever you start with a layout with more than one element I advise you to prefer a RelativeLayout in favor of the Linear thing. The RelativeLayout is very powerful and lets you position elements in relation to each other (leftOf, below, ...). In most cases that is more than you'll ever need.

An example from [the android development document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) (believe me it's all there):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reminder" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@id/times"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/times"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LinearLayout**

The LinearLayout might look very capable too but in order to get everything sorted with only Linears you'll most likely start nesting these layouts. And that's where it get's ugly performance wise.

Again an example from [the android development documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think `layout_weight` works inside a `RelativeLayout`. Maybe you should add a `LinearLayout` inside the `RelativeLayout` and use `layout_weight` inside.

Also when using `layout_weight` you usually have to have either the width or the height of the object defined as `0dp`, so in your case like this:

```
android:layout_weight="0.7"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this question is old, but just for someone who looking for a solution:

Google introduced new API called [android.support.percent](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?linkId=16439958#percent)

`PercentRelativeLayout` exactly your case:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <!-- Other controls -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:text="Σύνδεση"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyTextView"
        app:layout_widthPercent="70%"/>

    <!-- Other controls -->

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

layout_weight, works on the LinearLayout as parent. so i think the problem lies there. you have to use a mix of all linear layout and relative layouts to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not define `android:layout_weight="1.0"` in *Relative layout* tag, if you want to set the length of button other then the `"wrap_content"`

Comment: android:layout_weight only works for LinearLayout, not RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

As @hcpl correctly mentioned in his answer:

> You can't use the layout_weight parameters on a RelativeLayout. These are parameters from the LinearLayout.

Yep, he's right! But think about [negative impact on performance](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) caused by nested layouts.

With the introduction of ConstraintLayout, you can solve your problem without nested LinearLayout. You just paste two vertical guidelines with 15% and 85% margins and place your buttons between them.

[image: Layout Editor]

Here's the layout source code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="userVersionTextViewNew"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="userSoftSerialNumberTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userVersionTextViewNew"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_200"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dummyTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummyTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="dummyTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loginButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Σύνδεση"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dummyTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/leftGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/demoLoginButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/demoLoginButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Δοκιμαστική χρήση"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/leftGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/leftGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/rightGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a result you get this view:

[image: Result view]

You can find more details in [Building interfaces with ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7).

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="10"> 
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:textSize="15px"   
        android:id="@+id/userVersionTextViewNew" 
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
    /> 
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:textSize="15px" 
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:id="@+id/userSoftSerialNumberTextView"/> 
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/logo_200" 
        android:layout_weight="0.75"/>     
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:textSize="15px" 
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:id="@+id/dummyTextView"/>        
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:id="@+id/loginButton" 
        android:text="Σύνδεση" 
        android:layout_weight="3.5"/> 
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:id="@+id/demoLoginButton" 
        android:text="Δοκιμαστική χρήση" 
        android:layout_weight="3.5"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I suppose you mean 7.5 instead of 0.75.

Comment: no i mean 0.75...you want 70% to your button then..this will give 70% to last 2 button and rest 30% to above 4 text and image view..just try and tell me..

Comment: Still, the buttons are at 100% width and moreover, they occupate half my total window, more than 50% of the tab content.

Comment: the above code is to set the weight for the height ..not for width..how do you want to look the xml if possible post image above

Comment: In my original post I wrote about the button width at 70% of the total width. And my method could not work, so it's about fixing this issue.

Comment: I can post a screenshot, but I thought that it was obvious that the only thing I wanted was to make my buttons occupy the 70% of the total width. Anyway, screenshot incoming soon.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/screenshotwex.png/ I just want the 2 buttons to have with at 70% of the window.

Answer (score -2):

First, add the param `android:weightSum="1.0"` to the container (in this case, add it to RelativeLayout).

Then, define the weight of each of their children. For example, if you add to a button this

```
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:layout_width="0px"
```

the button will take 50% of total width.

Comment: It won't accept android:layout_width="0", it's "0px", but the buttons have disappeared.

Comment: Sorry, it is "0dp" or "0px" or similar... You must set this params in all children

Comment: The sum of all layout_weight must be equal to layout_weightSum

Comment: do the RelativeLayout have a android:weightSum param ?