# Why does the first relative grows a lot occupying all the screen, instead of share the space with all elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-layout-weight

I want to do something like this:

[image]

First of all I don't want a scroll View.

The second point is: I need a fixed footer.

So, the best way to work is with weight. When I put a weight in all relatives, the first relative grows a lot occupying all the screen, instead of share the space with all elements.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_app"
        tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/green_tataki"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                <!--Here the action bar-->
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/image_product"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent_header"
                android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"/>
            <!--Relative with background as image-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/image_product"
                android:background="@drawable/sushi">
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_product"
                android:id="@+id/box_description"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                <!--Text view inside relative-->
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!--Relative 1-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/box_description"
                android:id="@+id/quantity_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_left">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RELATIVE 1"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!--Relative 2-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/additional_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/quantity_button"
                android:background="@drawable/border_left">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RELATIVE 1"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--Relative 3-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/additional_button"
                android:background="@drawable/border_left">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="RELATIVE 3"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--Relative 4-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/delete_button"
                android:background="@drawable/border_left"
                android:id="@+id/clarification_button">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="RELATIVE 4"
                        />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--Button-->
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_to_car"
                    android:textColor="@color/brown_tataki"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/clarification_button"
                    android:background="@color/green_tataki"
                    android:text="@string/add_to_car"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <!--Footer-->
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent_footer"
            android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/green_tataki"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RELATIVE 4"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
<!--Menu-->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/brown_tataki"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: your mistake is quit simple - you added weight only for Relatives. Moreover with the same value and it seems you think about weight like scaleXY. Read my answer below. Any qestion high appreciate

Answer (score 0):

As I see you set the same value to all `RelativeLayout` so they would take identical amount of space, but it not means that thay would be two times smaller

Weight doesn't means the same what scale ;-)

You should add weight parameter to ALL of your views if you want to see a ViewGroup as on image, but before ... please read carefully: [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

#### Here's my all-time favorite explanation for `layout_weight`

> If there are multiple views spanning a `LinearLayout`, then
>   `layout_weight` gives them each a proportional size. A view with a
>   bigger `layout_weight` value "weighs" more, so it gets a bigger space.
>
> Here is an image to make things more clear.
>
> [image]
>
> ### Theory
>
> The term layout weight is related to the concept of [weighted
>   average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) in math. It is like in a college class where homework is
>   worth 30%, attendance is worth 10%, the midterm is worth 20%, and the
>   final is worth 40%. Your scores for those parts, when weighted
>   together, give you your total grade.
>
> [image]
>
> It is the same for layout weight. The `Views` in a horizontal
>   `LinearLayout` can each take up a certain percentage of the total
>   width. (Or a percentage of the height for a vertical `LinearLayout`.)
>
> ### The Layout
>
> The `LinearLayout` that you use will look something like this:
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>     <!-- list of subviews -->
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> Note that you must use `layout_width="match_parent"` for the
>   `LinearLayout`. If you use `wrap_content`, then it won't work. Also
>   note that `layout_weight` does not work for the views in
>   RelativeLayouts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16708014/3681880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14009266/3681880) for SO answers dealing
>   with this issue).
>
> ### The Views
>
> Each view in a horizontal `LinearLayout` looks something like this:
>
> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_weight="1" />
> ```
>
> Note that you need to use `layout_width="0dp"` together with
>   `layout_weight="1"`. Forgetting this causes many new users problems.
>   (See [this article](http://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/) for different results you can get by not
>   setting the width to 0.) If your views are in a *vertical*
>   `LinearLayout` then you would use `layout_height="0dp"`, of course.
>
> In the `Button` example above I set the weight to 1, but you can use
>   any number. It is only the total that matters. You can see in the
>   three rows of buttons in the first image that I posted, the numbers
>   are all different, but since the proportions are the same, the
>   weighted widths don't change in each row. Some people like to use
>   decimal numbers that have a sum of 1 so that in a complex layout it is
>   clear what the weight of each part is.
>
> One final note. If you have lots of nested layouts that use
>   `layout_weight`, it can be bad for performance.
>
> ### Extra
>
> Here is the xml layout for the top image:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="android:layout_weight="
>         android:textSize="24sp" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:text="1" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="2"
>             android:text="2" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:text="1" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="android:layout_weight="
>         android:textSize="24sp" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="10"
>             android:text="10" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="20"
>             android:text="20" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="10"
>             android:text="10" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="android:layout_weight="
>         android:textSize="24sp" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight=".25"
>             android:text=".25" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight=".50"
>             android:text=".50" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight=".25"
>             android:text=".25" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

If you have any question please free to ask.

Hope it help

Comment: I read everything you suggest, I understand, and I fixed a way that works, but it is growing the first element, instead of improving :(

Comment: update your code and  I would test it in my Android Studio and devices. Don't waorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:weight_sum="10"`in the parent view that contains the subviews then use the `layout_weight` to give them the ratio

Comment: I put it, but it still show the first relative in all the screen :(