# How to make ImageView as large as possible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_item_cardview_margin"
                                    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/news_image_description"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/news_image1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_image1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_pub_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/news_title"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/news_title"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/news_image1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_image1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_comments_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_comment_black_18dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_comment_black_18dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Layout I want to create]

I want to create a layout like image 1 with layout xml above. But when i test it, I found the image view isn't large enough. it could be higher and wider.

[image: layout in emulator]

how could i make the imageview have more priority than textview.

Comment: do you want this to support all device having different resolution ?

Comment: @Wei Jian guo take imagview's width large not wrap content

Comment: yes, that's why i didn't indicate layout_width manually. @AmitVaghela

Comment: check this answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/37295089/2826147, you can use it with minor changes to support all devices

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!

add

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/news_image_description"/>
```

Comment: could you explain why relativelayout behave like this.

Comment: it works, however the image was cropped. is it better to use PercentLayout? if i want the image to keep its ratio

Comment: you may want to set a fixed value for it

Answer (score 1):

check below layout file, in which changed from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and used **weightSum**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:contentDescription="news_image_description"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="Title"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_pub_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:hint="Date"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_comments_count"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:hint="Count"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout >
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `weight` and `weightSum` properties inside tags.
E.g.,
android:layout_weight="0.7"

read this question: [Android relative layout with button width using weight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7846614/1979882)

Comment: how it possible to make large size of image in imageview? Did you try this ever @Vyacheslav?

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this into your CardView

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:weightSum="3"
android:padding="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/news_image1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_pub_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Some"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_comments_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end|right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Count"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the output i got
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest programmatically solution for you. You have to compute the best proportions for your ImageView without changing orginal image's aspect ratio.

```
private void fitImageView(View parentView, ImageView imageView) {
    double maxHeight = parentView.getLayoutParams().height - parentView.getPaddingTop() - parentView.getPaddingBottom();
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();

    double width = drawable.getMinimumWidth();
    double height = drawable.getMinimumHeight();
    double aspect = (float) width / height;

    width = maxHeight * aspect;
    height = maxHeight;

    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) height;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) width;
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}
```