# GridView items: set relative sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm trying to display some items in a `GridView`. I want each item to fill a relative part of the screen (`image B`) and all I have is `GridView` take just the space it needs at the top of the screen (`image A`). The image:

[image]

(I want each item sizes over 15-20% height of the main layout)

**EDIT :** I found this question [Percentage width in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout). 'LadaRaider' gives a good answer but I don't know how to use that solution in my `GridView` cells. This is my `layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background">

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/label_name"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/ll_ok"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/lbl_choose"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <GridView
     android:id="@+id/grid"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:columnWidth="100dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/ll_wait"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/lbl_wait"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I have also created a custom layout to use in `GridView` items. It has just a `TextView` and a background.