# Android Layout Weight not working with relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

[image]

I am trying to implement layout weight for the first time, a bit I tried with linear layout it works good, but when I tried with relative and linear layout something went wrong. What is wrong here?

My XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Linearlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="45" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:spacing="4dip" >
    </Gallery>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Rlayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/makerback" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerphoto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/makerphoto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerselves"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/makerselves" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerskins"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/makerskins" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makersave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/makersave" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to achieve the above image:

Comment: can you share the image what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 11):

> You cannot use percentages to define the dimensions of a View inside a
>   RelativeLayout. The best ways to do it is to use LinearLayout and
>   weights, or a custom Layout. 
>   -Romain Guy

[Percentage width in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout)

From Docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight

**UPDATE**

We can now use [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) . Example from docs:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: ...except the OP is trying to define the dimensions of a `RelativeLayout` itself, not of a view inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: (Please notice the change within star symbol)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        *android:layout_height="0dp"*
        android:layout_weight="45" >

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:spacing="4dip" >
        </Gallery>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Rlayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        *android:layout_height="0"*
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/navbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        *android:layout_height="0"*
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makerback"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/makerback" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makerphoto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/makerphoto" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makerselves"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/makerselves" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makerskins"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/makerskins" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makersave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/makersave" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use weight like that. Try

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight=1
    ... />
```

for example.

Comment: PrimoZ so no need to add weight sum?

Comment: don't put the relative layout in side the linear layout, and then try it

Answer (score 0):

this may be use full

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"  >
        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:spacing="4dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        </Gallery>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/Rlayout1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
           android:orientation="vertical" >


       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:scaleType="fitXY" />

     </RelativeLayout> -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numbers"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/forword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numbers"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with traditional layout hierarchy but you should be aware of nested layout's negative impact on UI performance. Read [Understanding the performance benefits of ConstraintLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) for reference.

To flatten your layout and use percentage values you can use ConstraintLayout's guidelines:

[image: Layout Editor]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:spacing="4dip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerback"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerphoto"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/verGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerselves"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/verGuideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makerskins"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/verGuideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makersave"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/verGuideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horGuideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horGuideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```