# TextView overlap in ListView implementation android with 2 textviews

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing listview with 2 textviews , and for reference used [Basic Layout and Formatting](http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/09/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-iii-%E2%80%93-basic-layout-and-formatting/)

Instead of stock names which are short i am using long text, so when i use a long text, it overlaps with the second .

So how to get it right, so that the 2 textviews don't overlap each other.

Comment: [see this example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used following code to solve your problem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ticker_symbol"

         android:text="sdasd sadas"
         android:layout_weight=".5"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ticker_price"
         android:text="dfsd"
         android:layout_weight=".5"
         android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image: Output of Code]

Comment: i am using relative layout instead of linear layout , so it won't work with that

Comment: is there any specific reason to use  linear layout

Comment: Hi , i have one more question .if the content of first text view will increase , then the content of text view will go to next line or did not display ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overlapping, you could set the second textview to align to right (android:layout_toRightOf).

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ticker_symbol"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ticker_price"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ticker_symbol"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes , it does that in the example , but it still overlaps one textview over the other , my 2nd textview doesn't shift at all , and first textview overlaps with it

Comment: The line `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ticker_symbol"` was added by me. It was not in the original example. Can you please add the XML code you are using so we can discuss on it?

Comment: You could also use the `android:weight` attribute to set the width to 50% for each textview instead of `wrap_content`. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout

Comment: the xml file is same which you posted above

Comment: again ,same as above , in relative layout i can't use android:weight

Comment: Maybe you could create a new `LinearLayout` inside the `RelativeLayout` containing the textviews and you can use android:weight. You can still keep RelativeLayout as the parent layout, if you need it for other eventual elements. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean due to long length of text it goes to next line or on next TextView

So i suggest you to use textView property android:ellipsized="end" and also use android:single_line="true" instead this you can directly specify the maxline=1 
I'm not sure with names spelled correctly so check while typing

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ticker_symbol"
        android:ellipsezed="end"
        android:singe_line="true"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Hope this explanation woks for you let me know..