# ImageButton Not Visible

Tags: java, android

Can someone please tell me why my `ImageButton` is not showing when I use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/continuebutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.02"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/continuebutton"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I use a `LinearLayout`, it shows up just fine. Can anyone please clarify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add layout_weight to a RelativeLayout - which doesn't make any sense. Relative layout places items relative to one another. They don't have their widths and heights calculated as a whole like what the LinearLayout does, because the flow matters on a Linear layout and not in a Relative layout.

Set the button to either wrap_content or match_parent. If you want weights, nest a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout.

Extra info on that here: [Percentage width in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout)

**EDIT**
LinearLayout looks at the weight AND 0dip values on its orientation when the calculations are made on how to layout its child views.. Say you have 2 items side by side in a horizontal linear-layout... if they are both 0dip width, the width will be calculated based on their weights. The RelativeLayout doesn't do this. It doesn't worry about the flow of items. It places items relative to one another's placing.

HTH

Comment: That didn't answer my question. Why does my button not display when I use the `RelativeLayout`? `Layout_weights` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It doesn't display because you have set the height to 0dip. The weight is irrelevant here.

Comment: LinearLayout looks at the weight AND 0dip values on its orientation. Say you have 2 items side by side in a horizontal linear-layout... if they are both 0dip width, the width will be calculated based on their weights. The RelativeLayout doesn't do this.

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't you just say that in the first place? Lol... Edit your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Also noticed you are setting orientation:"verticle" on a RelativeLayout... not a valid property.