# Google Play Store Layouts. Problems with apktool

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to see how they setup their layouts esp for a Google made app so I'm trying to use apktool to decompile it. However the framework is messed up and I can't apktool decompile the Play Store. Any ideas?

**Mostly I just want to know how they setup layouts where the screen space is so perfectly divided up.** Especially since the layouts have to handle different screen sizes, so how does Google setup their layouts to achieve this result, without bugs, when new devices and screen sizes are released on a frequent basis.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ouch!! Talk about _borrowing_ ideas. ;-)

Comment: LOL. I don't want to steal anything. I just want THE GOOGLE OFFICIAL way to divide up content area by percentage. I mean the first image has 3 content boxes perfectly consistent in size and space...HOW DID THEY DO THAT?!?!

Comment: No no. I said borrowing. ;-) And I suppose, to each his own. This is one way to find out. I would much rather falter a few times getting my hands dirty though. No clue how to help you on this. Never tried the apktool. Good luck fella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used this question/answer to go on...

[Percentage width in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout)

I had seen the weight property before, but this is the first time I'd seen weightSum, which actually makes a difference.