# How do I set the width of a child views to be divided amongst eachother?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a LinearLayout with the left view width being 80% of its parents width and the second view taking up the remaining space. How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout

It's about the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using android:layout_weight when defining your child Views.

For view 1 use a layout weight of 0.8 and view 2 use a layout weight of 0.2

Example xml would be :

```
android:layout_weight=".8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Don't forget to set the width to 0.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:background="@color/red" />
```