# Layout 4 Buttons in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-2.2-froyo

I'm pretty new to Android-development. I'm currently working on an app, where i need to layout 4 buttons on an screen. Button 1 + 2 should be in the first row and 3 + 4 in the second row. I want each button to be the same height and width. And as there are multiple screen sizes out there, i want the buttons-width be 40% of the screen width.
Is something like this possible to make just by layouting, or do i need to calculate everything in code?

Note: I want to deploy the app to devices running Android 2.2 or higher.

Here's a sample graphic.
[image]

EDIT: For all who are searching for the square stuff.. Here is the solution: http://android-layouts.com/category/tags/square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

so for solving this problem you must use `android:layout_weight="40/100"="0.4"`
and before it you must set `android:layout_width` to 0 .becuase without it `android:layout_weight="40/100"="0.4"` dont work.
for more details aboute ``android:layout_weight` go
[What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

`UPDATE 1`

for doing this task for height of button try below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thank's! That worked. If i want to make the buttons as height as they are width, do i have to do this in code?

Comment: I already solved the square problem with the help of this link: http://android-layouts.com/category/tags/square :)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961443/1427177):

> You cannot use percentages to define the dimensions of a View inside a RelativeLayout. The best ways to do it is to use LinearLayout and weights, or a custom Layout.

So what you are looking for is a `LinearLayout` and the `android:layout_weight` attribute.

The following code will create the layout from your screenshot:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start placing the first two buttons inside a horizontal LinearLayout, and the second 2 on another horizontal LinearLayout. Then add padding to the buttons to separate them. As far as the 40% maybe you can play with the weight XML attribute.