# overlapping children in RelativeLayout with percentage

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I want to put an ImageView on top of (over) another view which is derived from SurfaceView using percentages for width and height. But no idea how to achieve that. Any help?

That's my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <MyOwnView
        android:id="@+id/my_own_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
        android:src="@drawable/background_picture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And that's what I want:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout?rq=1

Comment: Indeed, I did. But it's completely different scenario because there are two elements using 30% and 70% of the space. In my scenario one view is behind the other. And I took the XML layout for my ImageView from that posting. But did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Frame Layout, the get overlapping views. Here's a little example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/my_own_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/my_own_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is an example of how you can do this. Instead of the image you embed another layout (in my example I choose a LinearLayout, but it can be a RelativeLayout, for example). In this inner-layout you arrange your views as usual. Note that I use a dummy view, along with the Imageview to give the **weight** some values. This weight is what allow you to specify percentages.

I hope this takes you into the right direction.

Comment: I don't see any FrameLayout in your example.

Comment: @Matthias I'm sorry, this was embarrassing, the formatter here thaught <FrameLayout> was an HTML tag!

Comment: Ok, but how do you specify a percentage for width/height for the ImageView?

Comment: This either works with FrameLayout and RelativeLayout. To get the ImageView into the upper left, you need another LinearLayout (horizontal) within the first (vertical) one. layout_weight has to be zero dot something (.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply warp your ImageView around a Linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<MyOwnView
    android:id="@+id/my_own_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight=".20"
       android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
       android:src="@drawable/background_picture" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need another place-holder (empty LinearView with some background color) for the remaining 80 percent. Otherwise it's not working because the ImageView will be shown as 100%.