# Scrollviews synchronisation issue

Tags: android, scrollview

I wrote a small app displaying 2 scrollViews next to each other. I need the scroll position of the 2 scrollViews to be synchronised. For that, I extended ScrollView and I overrode onScrollChanged to be notified when a scroll occurs, and then to sync the 2 scrollViews.

My two scroll views display a bunch of blue Views. The left scrollView has a red background, and the right has a green background.

Here is what happens with a scroll on the left scrollView:
[image: scroll on left scrollView]
=> The synchronisation is ok

And here is what happens with a scroll on the right scrollView:
[image: scroll on right scrollView]
=> The synchronisation is not good, there's a gap

(both screenshots were taken during the scrollviews' fling)

How to have a good synchronisation in both case?

The code of my Activity, my scrollView and my scrollView container is [here](https://github.com/MartinMoizard/scrollviewsync/tree/master/src/com/example/scrollviewsync).

Comment: Why do you use two ScrollViews instead of one?

Comment: I agree with @Médéric why not use just 1?

Comment: Because at some point, I need one to overlap the other.

Comment: Yes you were right after all. I didn't realize what was the problem at first. My mistake. Don't think you can avoid that latency with two `ScrollView`s though. What do you mean when you say one needs to overlap the other?

Comment: @Simas I mean that I want to position one scrollview over the other. That's why I cannot have the 2 contents concatenated in one scrollView.

Comment: You can just hide one of them can't you? Then the other one will take up all the space.

Comment: @Simas No, I need both of them to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you hit a system limitation here - the system draws the views in order they are declared in your XML.

Therefore, when you fling the first declared `ScrollView`, the second one gets updated but the first one is not updated again. When you fling the second one, however, the first one gets updated, then the second one gets updated, the change is reflected to the first one and it gets updated again.

I'm not sure that the above description is 100% accurate, but it is something along these lines.

I created a test case to check my hypothesis substituting the following for `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">


    <View android:id="@+id/separator_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>


    <com.example.www.syncscrollviewtesting_stackoverflow.ObservableScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/separator_view"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:id="@+id/left_scrollview">
        <com.example.www.syncscrollviewtesting_stackoverflow.Container
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100000dp"
            android:minHeight="100000dp"
            android:id="@+id/left_container"/>

    </com.example.www.syncscrollviewtesting_stackoverflow.ObservableScrollView>


    <com.example.www.syncscrollviewtesting_stackoverflow.ObservableScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/separator_view"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:id="@+id/right_scrollview">
        <com.example.www.syncscrollviewtesting_stackoverflow.Container
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100000dp"
            android:minHeight="100000dp"
            android:id="@+id/right_container"/>
    </com.example.www.syncscrollviewtesting_stackoverflow.ObservableScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above XML allows you to position both `ScrollView`s on either sides of the `separator_view`. I found out that no matter how you position them, a fling of the `ScrollView` having red background (declared second) always causes the "lag", while a fling of the `ScrollView` having green background works fine.

I also tried to prevent unnecessary updates of the `ScrollView`s by adding this to their code:

```
   @Override
   protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
      super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);
      if (!mIsDisabled && scrollViewListener != null) {
         scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, x, y, oldx, oldy);
      }
   }

   public void setDisabled(boolean isDisabled) {
      mIsDisabled = isDisabled;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      if (mIsDisabled)
         return false; // Ignore touch event when disabled
      else
         return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
   }
```

... and this to `Activity`'s:

```
   @Override
   public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
      if (scrollView == mRightScrollView) {
         mLeftScrollView.setDisabled(true);
         mLeftScrollView.setScrollY(y);
         mLeftScrollView.setDisabled(false);
      } else {
         mRightScrollView.setDisabled(true);
         mRightScrollView.setScrollY(y);
         mRightScrollView.setDisabled(false);
      }

   }
```

but it didn't help either...

So, I guess, you better find another approach which does not involve redrawing a whole lot of `Views`, or just accept the "lag".

**Solution:**
This solution was provided by the OP himself, based on my analysis of the situation: touch events can be forwarded from the right `ScrollView` (declared second in XML) to the left `ScrollView`. This way, given that flings on the left `ScrollView` do not cause lags, all touch events are treated as being initiated by the first declared `ScrollView` and the lag is avoided.

Comment: The child position is indeed linked to the scrollView having the sync issue. As a workaround, when a touch occurs on the right scrollView, I forward it to the left scrollView. It's a hack but that's the only solution I found to keep the 2 scrollViews all the time synced.

Comment: @MartinMoizard, I didn't even think about this simple solution. It is ingenious in its simplicity! Thanks for sharing back - I'll add this to the answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my previous answer hadn't properly studied your question.

As I've said, I don't think you can sync 2 `ScrollView`s properly without getting any latency at all. However you can still use a single view.

This gets a little trickier because you also want to split your split into equal parts with weight attribute.

The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784186/3249477). Building up on that I've come up with the following code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then when you want to toggle the `left` and `right` view overlapping call this:

```
leftParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0);
rightParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, 0);
```

and

```
leftParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.spacer);
rightParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.spacer);
```

after setting the params you need to redraw the view with:

```
left.requestLayout();
right.requestLayout();
```

---

A working example can be found on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/absimas/SyncedScrollView).