# How to give layout weight in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have created a dialpad using `LinearLayout`. Here is the code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_three"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="6" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="8" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="9" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="*" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="0" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="64dp"
                android:text="#" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which looks like this

[image]

Now i want the same in `RelativeLayout`, but i find `layout_weight` doesn't work in `RelativeLayout`. I also don't want to use `LinearLayout` inside `RelativeLayout`.
Or is there any alternative which can work same like `layout_weight` works in `LinearLayout` but for `RelativeLayout`

Comment: What do you need it for? Why do you want to use a RelativeLayout? Why not put the LinearLayout into the RelativeLayout?

Comment: I want to create a dialpad using RelativeLayout

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions.

Comment: is there a way to divide screen in RelativeLayout, Like in LinearLayout using layout_weight?

Comment: In a `RelativeLayout` you typically do not need weights because you can specify a view to align with another one.

Comment: Well just to understand more about RelativeLayout. Just want to Practice & its Behavior

Comment: You can use gridview? It will avoid nested view hierarchy, which ll be pbm in terms of performance

Answer (score 3):

> You cannot use percentages to define the dimensions of a View inside a RelativeLayout. The best ways to do it is to use LinearLayout and weights, or a custom Layout.

Fore more information you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with relative layout you can try to change the locations through the code. get the height and width of the outer layout using:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
rl.getWidth();
rl.getHeight();
```

and then get the params of the layout you want to evenly distribute:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50); //here i created a new one with size 50,50
```

now you can set `params.leftMargin` and `params.topMargin` the way you want with any calculation.

```
params.leftMargin = rl.getWidth()/4 ;
```

for example will set the new layout at the 1/4 of the screen width

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` is not a good choice because it doesn't provide a way you to evenly distribute children the way `LinearLayout` does. If you want something other than nested `LinearLayout`s, you can try using [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) (**not** `GridView`).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `layout_weight` in RelativeLayout. Looking over your XML, your current layout is poorly structured which will lead to poor performance. I suggest that you use either [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or Use your current LinearLayout but instead of assigning a LinearLayout to each number/character you can do something like this instead (Only for first row, but you get the idea):

`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LL_topRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Next LinearLayout Here for next row -->
```

`