# RelativeLayout ignoring size set by child

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that looks roughly like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="50dp"
    layout_alignParentTop="true"
    id="@+/A"/>
  <TextView
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="46dp"
    layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    id="@+/B"/>
  <CustomView 
    layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout_below="@id/A"
    layout_above="@id/B"
    layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The intention is that A and B should go at the top and bottom with fixed heights, and CustomView should take as much of the remaining space as it can subject to a constraint on its aspect ratio. 
(Note I can't use LinearLayout because of some other children I have omitted)

Here's what happens for a particular screen size:

- CustomView.onMeasure is called with (AT_MOST 776, AT_MOST 395)
- CustomView calls setMeasuredDimension(285, 391)
- CustomView.onMeasure called again with (EXACTLY 285, EXACTLY 251)
- CustomView calls setMeasuredDimension (arguments don't seem to matter)
- CustomView.onLayout called with dimensions 285 x 251

I guess the top and bottom constraints force height to be 251, but why doesn't RelativeLayout give CustomView a chance to choose a width based on this height constraint? It seems incorrect behaviour of RelativeLayout to assume that if a child can be 285x391, then it can also be 285x251. Is there a workaround (besides replacing RelativeLayout by another custom view)?

I'm using minSdkVersion=14 and targetSdkVersion=21, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code like this

`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TOP TEXT"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Bottom text"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:background="#820f22"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/A"
        android:layout_above="@+id/B"
        android:background="#0ff0ff"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`

and you can check it work good for me, you can try to change your custom view height to "match_parent" and remove gravity orientation

Comment: I tried with all combinations of wrap_content/match_parent for height and centerInParent/centerHorizontal/no gravity. For the height constrained case, all produce this: http://i.imgur.com/vrE0qxa.png. Note the aqua background indicates the ImageView is not square, though the image is centered inside the ImageView. Maybe I can't assume that CustomView can choose its aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

just put weight and height to match parent to center view and also remove layout_above as you can find in my code.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="50dp"
    layout_alignParentTop="true"
    id="@+/A"/>
  <TextView
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="46dp"
    layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    id="@+/B"/>
  <CustomView 
    layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout_height="match_parent"
    layout_below="@id/A"
    weight=1
    layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The reason behind this code work is your top and bottom view has fix value so layout has to make space for it even center view has weightage with 1.
*sorry for typo.*

Comment: layout_weight has no effect in a RelativeLayout
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31345745/1710519
Removing layout_above causes the child to stretch to the bottom
http://i.imgur.com/yRZaYpo.png