# Android sudokod layout

Tags: android, android-layout, sudoku

I want to develop a simple sudoku app. For the layout, I need to have a 9x9 table/grid for the board, and 12 buttons under it and all this must fit in one screen,i had a couple of ideas but there is a problem in each of them

1. Using `GridView` and pass a 2d array to the adapter, BUT, the grid is scrollable and the player must see the whole board.
2. Using `TableView`, but its not clickable as the grid.
3. Create 81 button for the board in the xml or programmatically, I think it will be complex.

Is there are any other simpler or more efficient ideas! And if not , which one from the above is better.

Comment: Weighted buttons inside of `LinearLayout`'s.

Comment: Can't you disable the scroll-ability of the grid view? Or fill the tableview with buttons (via a loop) and make it clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option for getting this done using weighted width and height. As far as I know this feature is only available in `LinearLayout`s.

The main idea I've just explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057864/1841194).

Please first off read the answer I linked to and then you could use the following approach to laying out your buttons.

1. Declare a main vertical `LinearLayout` and set its width and height to `match_parent`.
2. Add 9 horizontal `LinearLayout`s while their width is set to `match_parent` and their height set to `0dp` with `layout_weigth` equal to `1`.
3. Add 9 buttons (i.e. your cells) to each `LinearLayout` while their width is set to `0dp` and `layout_weight` set to `1` and their height is set to `match_parent`.