# How to pair the height of two EditTexts - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

I have two `EditTexts` side by side in my application.

This is what they look like with 1 line of input

[image]

Currently when I type multiple lines of input in one `EditText` grows but the other stays the same height - as seen here

[image]

I want the `EditTexts` to match in height. When one grows the other matches it's height - as seen here

[image]

Not sure how to achieve this effect. I don't want to fill in the other `EditText` with new lines. I want the actual `View` to grow.

This is my current layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top|start"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top|start"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to make the EditText height match the parent

Comment: @cricket_007 tried that and the `EditTexts` stay as one line and don't grow

Comment: How about a TableLayout instead of LinearLayout?

Comment: try using RelativeLayout and using
`android:layout_alignBottom="@id/left"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/left"` for `EditText` right

Comment: @PhanVanLinh how can the parent target the children `ids`? They're not declared yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the height of the other edittext in the onTextChange method... example

```
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //Change your other layout height here 

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Leave that simply what i am saying is change the other Edittext width from the onTExtChanged method..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following,

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784186/2367703) answer. Based on the answer linked, I created this solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/right"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your java code do this:

```
        editTextLeft = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.left);
        editTextRight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.right);
        editTextLeft.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editTextLeft.getLayoutParams();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editTextRight.getLayoutParams();
                    leftLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
                    rightLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,editTextLeft.getId());
                    int lines = editTextRight.getLineCount() > editTextLeft.getLineCount() ? editTextRight.getLineCount() : editTextLeft.getLineCount();
                    editTextLeft.setMinLines(lines);
                    editTextRight.setMinLines(lines);
                    editTextLeft.setLayoutParams(leftLayoutParams);
                    editTextRight.setLayoutParams(rightLayoutParams);

                }
            }
        });
        editTextRight.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if(b) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editTextLeft.getLayoutParams();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editTextRight.getLayoutParams();
                    rightLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
                    leftLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, editTextRight.getId());
                    int lines = editTextRight.getLineCount() > editTextLeft.getLineCount() ? editTextRight.getLineCount() : editTextLeft.getLineCount();
                    editTextLeft.setMinLines(lines);
                    editTextRight.setMinLines(lines);
                    editTextLeft.setLayoutParams(leftLayoutParams);
                    editTextRight.setLayoutParams(rightLayoutParams);
                }
            }
        });
```