# How can I specify that this ImageView have to be shown smaller?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am absolutly new in Android development and I am findig the following problem working on my first app.

My problem is related to changing the space occupied by an image into my layout.

So I have a situation like this: I don't put the image directly into my XML layout file but I do it programatically into my activity code calling this method:

```
ImageView difficultyContainerImageView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.difficultyContainer);

difficultyContainerImageView1.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), ImgUtility.createRankingImg(context, 3)));
```

So the **ImgUtility.createRankingImg(context, 3)** return a **Bitmap** object that is setted into the **ImgeView** of my layout having **difficultyContainer** as ID.

It works fine and the image is showed into my layout, this one:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/pastaTitleTextStyle" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
            android:text="Difficoltà:" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/difficultyContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The image is correctly showed into this **ImageView**:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/difficultyContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

The only problem is that doing in this way the image horizontally occupy all the space of the view, this is what I obtained (the image is the last one that contains the chef hats):

[image]

It should depends by the fact that I am using **android:layout_width="fill_parent"** to say that the **ImageView** having **id=difficultyContainer** have to horizontally occupy all the spac of its container (the main **LinearLayout**).

So I want know how can I set a percentual width\height for this **ImageView**.

What is the best way to specify a percentage so my image will be shown smaller in my app? What is the best solution to do it?

Comment: what I get is you want to set width of image view manually (by programmatic way) ?

Comment: I think you should be able to search for "percent layout android"...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32168421/2308683

Comment: @dex no, I want to do it into my XML definition

Comment: can you show us how do you want the image to be like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to ask how to set the size of the imageView programmatically?

If so use:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.difficultyContainer);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
```

The same for height, just replace width with height.

This value of '120' being in dp, which means the size of the image will adjust depending on the screen size of the output device, meaning you don't need to utilise percentages like you would in html/css

Comment: ok, interesting, so if I set the width in my XML view definition using the DP it is related to the specific used display and I can avoid to specifu a percentage?

Comment: yes exactly :) 1 dp = the size of one physical pixel on the device screen, so these sizes will differ from device to device

find more information here in the 'Density Independence' section:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to your ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/difficultyContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```