# Android Layout 3 Items With Different Widths In Same Line

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I would like to know how I can put 3 different elements with different widths in the same line?

Like below

LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation (parent) within that,
Textview(50% width-align left)ImageView(25% width-align right)Textview(25% width-align right) all in the same line?

Please help.

Comment: Did you check attribute `android:layout_weight` for child views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` with weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_landing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## Or

You can use `PercentRelativeLayout` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout/32168421#32168421)

Comment: @joelj welcome,  if that helped you do vote up as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 RelativeLayouts with respective weights inside a LinearLayout of horizontal orientation.