# Android layout: How show all images evenly distributed on the window

Tags: android

i try to create a Android-App that using all images from
[gitHub png-images 0ad](https://github.com/0ad/0ad/blob/master/binaries/data/mods/public/art/textures/ui/session/portraits/emblems).

i try to put all (about 19) images at the screen.
i tried to set the image size to 17% of the screen (or 0.17).

if i set all to `layout_width="match_parent"` images are to large.
if i set images to `layout_width="50dp"` images are to small for some devices.

my idea was to use (because i have read [android.com..multiscreen](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#kotlin)
`resources.displayMetrics * 0.10` as image size.

I also tried many answers from [Percentage width in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout). Seems outdated.

full source: https://github.com/0ad-matters/0ad-counter-unit-guide

My best Solution in `app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml` at the moment
shows images to small:

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:minWidth="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="match_parent"
        android:maxWidth="match_parent"
        android:maxHeight="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_athenians"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"/>
                <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_britons"
                />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

TabkeRow
match_parent for layout_width and layout_height looks like this:

[image]

if i use `wrap_content` for with of a image it takes 100% of the image size. thats to large as you could see here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the widths to "0dp" and the heights to "wrap_content"?

Comment: @Rob you mean without using a table? i did not. You mean the width, height of the ImageButtons ?

Comment: I don't think that works anymore with tables. some kind of grid i guess is expected.

Comment: Yes, removing the table. I'll post a more detailed answer below.

Comment: Grid layout might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it: Remove the table create a new ConstraintLayout for each row of ImageButtons. Set the constraints for each button to the next button in the row, creating a chain of constraints across the layout. Constrain the top of the second row to the bottom of the first row. For brevity, I only did four buttons per row, but this will work with as many as you want to add.

Also, set adjustViewBounds to true and scale the images if you'd like to include the entire image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r1col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/r1col2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_athenians" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r1col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r1col1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/r1col3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_britons" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r1col3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r1col2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/r1col4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_carthaginians" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r1col4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r1col3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_han" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r2col1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/r2col2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_kushites" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r2col2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r2col1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/r2col3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_macedonians" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r2col3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r2col2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/r2col4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_macedonians2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/r2col4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/r2col3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/emblem_mauryas" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result: [image: Justified buttons]