# website screen resolution auto resolution

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a website for my stuff and now I realize when I am trying thru different browsers.
The way in which it looks is completely different. I used Dreamweaver CS5.5 as the base for creating it.

Is there some element that I am missing to add.

I tried glancing thru the forum for some results. I tried out :
[How to adapt website to user's Screen Resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779077/how-to-adapt-website-to-users-screen-resolution)

No doughnut with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would read a bit on Responsive webdesign:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/